# How to integrate $\frac{4x}{x^3+x^2+x+1}$

Tags: calculus

I'd like to know how to integrate $$\frac{4x}{x^3+x^2+x+1}$$

Please could anyone help me

Thanks all

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: How about some factoring here?

Comment: @imranfat I don't know how to factoring something like this

Comment: The rational root theorem will find you the factor $x+1$.  Then you have a quadratic which (if you don't see how to factor it) will yield to the quadratic formula.

Comment: @Ross it will become (x+1)(x^2+1) right?

Comment: That is right.  Then $x^2+1$ has no real roots, but does factor as $(x+i)(x-i)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1)$. We use **partial fracions**. So we try to find constants $A,B,C$ such that
$$\frac{4x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}.$$
Bring the right-hand side to the common denominator $(x+1)(x^2+1)$. The numerators must be identically equal. It follows that
$$4x=A(x^2+1)+(Bx+C)(x+1).$$
Set $x=-1$. We get $-4=2A$, and therefore $A=-2$.

On the right, the coefficient of $x^2$ is $-2+B$. On the left it is $0$. It follows that $B=2$.

On the right, the coefficient of $x$ is therefore $2+C$. Thus $C=2$. We conclude that
$$\frac{4x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=-\frac{2}{x+1}+\frac{2x+2}{x^2+1}.$$

So we want to integrate $-\frac{2}{x+1}+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}+\frac{2}{x^2+1}$.

The rest is straightforward. To integrate $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ let $u=x^2+1$.

Answer (score 3):

The denominator has roots $i$ , $-1$ and $-i$ so you can write it in the following way $$
\frac{4x}{(x-i)(x+1)(x+i)}$$

Now separate it into partial fractions and integrate each of them individually .